# PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...) call calling the setter again when stepping through a Set statement

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, event-handling

I have a simple base class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  The code works.  But when I was stepping through a Set statement, when the Set statement called SetProperty(), I noticed that the PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...) call was calling the setter again.

So the setter code in the subclass looks something like:

```
private string someProperty ;
public string SomeProperty { get => someProperty ;
set {
    // Do some tests on value to make sure it's valid
    SetProperty(ref someProperty, value);
    // Now do some other stuff once that is set
}
```

When I step through it the call stack shows:

- SomeProperty.Set( valuetype value);  ????? Why again????  --- 5
- External Code --- 4
- OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName ) --- 3
- SetProperty(field, value) --- 2
- SomeProperty.Set( valuetype value) ---- Initial set execution

Code snippet:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{        
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        Dev.Tools.Assert(propertyName != null, "propertyName can't be null.... ");
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    // This is used to support change tracking.  But 
    //   the problem happens even when TrackChangedFields is false.
    // The EqualityComparer prevents this from being recursive.
    public virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            field = newValue;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            if (TrackChangedFields && !IgnoreFieldList.Contains(propertyName))
            {
                ChangedFieldList.Add(new ChangedRecordDetail(propertyName, field, newValue, ViewModelName));
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Any idea why the PropertyChanged?.Invoke() call is causing the set to fire again?

Again, this code works fine.  I just don't understand why the 2nd call to the setter is happening nor what to do to only have the setter called once.

Comment: It is most likely because of your `if (TrackChanged...` conditional statement. Because I [just tested your code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YWScsSNpqK4a6f1y_UsUhW7JaNkZEoO6/view?usp=sharing) without that conditional statement and it only fires once.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will look into that.  I should have pulled the code when testing, but TrackFields was false during testing, so the 2nd reference shouldn't have fired.